# How to refresh AWS authentication token for EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I am authenticating via the following

First I authenticate into AWS via the following

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region cn-north-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn
```

Then I created the `regcred` file that I reference in my deployment config

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/noobskie/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

So this was working fine the first 12 hours but now that the AWS token has expired I am having trouble figuring out how to properly refresh it. I have rerun the first command but it doesn't work.

the error I get is

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/baopals, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
```

**EDIT**

I have just discovered that I can just reconfigure with the following command but I am curious if this is the correct way to handle it and if there are any other AWS ways offered.

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/noobskie/.docker/config.json --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to generate token if aws-cli and aws-iam-authenticator is installed and configured.

```
aws-iam-authenticator token -i cluster name
```